# Keras Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) :

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, rstudio

I am doing deep learning using Keras in Rstudio.I copy and paste this link https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/tutorials/beginners/basic-ml/tutorial_basic_regression/

```
boston_housing <- dataset_boston_housing()

c(train_data, train_labels) %<-% boston_housing$train
c(test_data, test_labels) %<-% boston_housing$test

paste0("Training entries: ", length(train_data), ", labels: ", length(train_labels))

train_data[1, ] # Display sample features, notice the different scales

library(dplyr)

column_names <- c('CRIM', 'ZN', 'INDUS', 'CHAS', 'NOX', 'RM', 'AGE', 
                  'DIS', 'RAD', 'TAX', 'PTRATIO', 'B', 'LSTAT')

train_df <- train_data %>% 
  as_tibble(.name_repair = "minimal") %>% 
  setNames(column_names) %>% 
  mutate(label = train_labels)

test_df <- test_data %>% 
  as_tibble(.name_repair = "minimal") %>% 
  setNames(column_names) %>% 
  mutate(label = test_labels)

train_labels[1:10] # Display first 10 entries

spec <- feature_spec(train_df, label ~ . ) %>% 
  step_numeric_column(all_numeric(), normalizer_fn = scaler_standard()) 

spec <- fit(spec)

layer <- layer_dense_features(
  feature_columns = dense_features(spec), 
  dtype = tf$float32
)

layer(train_df)

layer(train_df)

Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  ValueError: ('We expected a dictionary here. Instead we got: ',          CRIM    ZN  INDUS  CHAS     NOX  ...    TAX  PTRATIO       B  LSTAT  label
0     1.23247   0.0   8.14   0.0  0.5380  ...  307.0     21.0  396.90  18.72   15.2
1     0.02177  82.5   2.03   0.0  0.4150  ...  348.0     14.7  395.38   3.11   42.3
**sessionInfo()**
```

R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Chile.1252  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Chile.1252    LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Chile.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=Spanish_Chile.1252

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.8.5      tfdatasets_2.0.0 keras_2.2.5.0    tensorflow_2.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.3         pillar_1.4.3       compiler_3.6.3     prettyunits_1.1.1  base64enc_0.1-3    tools_3.6.3
 [7] progress_1.2.2     zeallot_0.1.0      digest_0.6.25      packrat_0.5.0      jsonlite_1.6.1     evaluate_0.14
[13] tibble_2.1.3       pkgconfig_2.0.3    rlang_0.4.5        cli_2.0.2          rstudioapi_0.11    yaml_2.2.1
[19] xfun_0.12          knitr_1.28         generics_0.0.2     vctrs_0.2.4        rappdirs_0.3.1     hms_0.5.3
[25] tidyselect_1.0.0   reticulate_1.14    glue_1.3.2         forge_0.2.0        R6_2.4.1           fansi_0.4.1
[31] rmarkdown_2.1      purrr_0.3.3        magrittr_1.5       whisker_0.4        tfestimators_1.9.1 tfruns_1.4
[37] htmltools_0.4.0    assertthat_0.2.1   crayon_1.3.4

Answer (score 3):

Can you please try the fix mentioned [here](https://github.com/rstudio/keras/issues/33).

Provided the solution below as well if in case the link is broken -

To install the fix you should be sure to close all R sessions then open a fresh R session and execute:

```
devtools::install_github("rstudio/reticulate")
```

The reason you need to close all R sessions is that windows shared libraries won't be successfully overwritten if they are in use during the installation.

Hope this works and fixes the issue you are facing.

Comment: Unfortunately the solution above did not work here... Here I see also: Detailed traceback:
  File "/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36_automl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 822, in __call__
    outputs = self.call(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36_automl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/feature_column/dense_features.py", line 129, in call
    features)

Traceback:

1. layer(train_df)
2. py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords)